# Faster way to open a private window from a link?

Tags: safari

To open a link in a private window, you have to hold down the option key and right click on the link and then select private browsing from the menu. It's mildly irritating. Anyone know of a way to hack safari to make this easier? Would be better, for example, to just be able to hold down the option key and left click.